# Encontrar primer y último mes con valores distintos a 0

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo la siguiente tabla en Excel:

```
| ID | Descripción | Año | Enero | Febrero | Marzo | Abril | Mayo | Junio | Julio | Agosto | Septiembre | Octubre | Noviembre | Diciembre |
```

En cada mes pueden existir valores entre el 0 y el 10.000. Lo que necesito saber es cuál es el primer y el último mes con valores distintos a cero.

Es decir, si tengo por ejemplo: Año 2015, y en los meses desde enero a marzo "0" luego desde abril a octubre valores distintos a 0 y finalmente de noviembre a diciembre 0 nuevamente, necesito que me muestre en otras 2 columnas:

```
Inicio = Abril | Fin = Octubre.
```

¿Es posible?

Edición: Para encontrar el primer distinto de 0 funciona esto:

```
=COINCIDIR(VERDADERO;D2:02>0;0))
```

Pero para el último todavía no se cómo hacer.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tu tabla es así:

```
ID | Descripción | Año  | Enero | Febrero | Marzo | Abril | Mayo | Junio | Julio | Agosto | Septiembre | Octubre | Noviembre | Diciembre | Inicio       | Fin   
1  | Hola        | 2015 | 0     | 0       | 0     | 1     | 2    | 3     | 4     | 5      | 6          | 7       | 0         | 0         |              |
2  | Ciao        | 2016 | 0     | 0       | 3     | 4     | 5    | 6     | 7     | 8      | 9          | 0       | 0         | 0         |              |
```

Para obtener el primer mes podrías hacer algo como esto para Inicio:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$O$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D2:O2<>0,),0))
```

Y para el último mes algo como esto para Fin:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$O$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D2:O2<>0,),1))
```

(misma fórmula, sólo cambiando el tipo de coincidencia de 0 a 1). Aquí dejo una captura de pantalla de cómo se ve en mi Excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siento, uso Excel en inglés, parece que los [equivalentes en español](http://www.xperimentos.com/2007/03/03/tabla-de-traduccion-de-formulas-excel-en-espanol-a-ingles/) serían `INDICE` para `INDEX` y `COINCIDIR` para `MATCH`, con lo que quedaría así:

```
=INDICE($D$1:$O$1,COINCIDIR(TRUE,INDICE(D2:O2<>0,),0))

=INDICE($D$1:$O$1,COINCIDIR(TRUE,INDICE(D2:O2<>0,),1))
```

La solución es una variante de la solución dada a esta [respuesta en SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/671458).

Comment: Para el último no funciona, sólo muestra un "0"

Comment: @Pepemujica ¿Qué formula has puesto para el último?¿Puedes copiarla aquí?

Comment: =INDICE(D2:O2;COINCIDIR(VERDADERO;INDICE(D2:O2<>0;);1))

Comment: @Pepemujica fíjate como en la fórmula que yo pongo, el primer INDICE es sobre `D1:O1` y no sobre `D2:O2` como tienes puesto. Cambia eso, prueba de nuevo y dime cómo va

Comment: Estoy viendo que a veces funciona y otras no, por ejemplo, si pongo en Enero, abril, julio y octubre el valor 12500 y en el resto de los meses 0, me arroja Inicio en enero y fin en Diciembre, cuando en realidad debería mostrar fin ocubre

Comment: Es raro. He estado haciendo pruebas cambiando valores por 0 o por 1 y el resultado parece inconsistente. Voy a ver que pasa y actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que es porque los meses no 0 no son consecutivos, por eso falla la función, pero no se cómo corregirla

Comment: Deberías quitar la marca de respuesta aceptada, de lo contrario puede que haya gente que sepa la respuesta pero no entre porque piense que ya encontraste una

Comment: Listo, ya la quité!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la misma funcion `={COINCIDIR(VERDADERO;D2:02>0;0)}`, solo debes cambiar el último cero por uno, para que te devuelva el último, `{COINCIDIR(VERDADERO;D2:02>0;1)}`

Comment: Probé, pero no funciona, simplemente me indica la última celda, tenga o no un 0

Answer (score 0):

## Fórmulas de matriz

> NOTA: Luego de escribir la fórmula, oprimir <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Mayúsculas</kbd> + <kbd>Intro</kbd>

Inicio: `=INDEX(C1:N1,,MIN(IF(C2:N2>0,COLUMN(C2:N2)-2,13)))`

> NOTA: Se ha indicado `13` como valor para FALSO asumiendo que siempre habrá un mes con un valor mayor que `0`.

Fin: `=INDEX(C1:N1,,MAX(IF(C2:N2>0,COLUMN(C2:N2)-2,0)))`

> NOTA: Se ha indicado `0` como valor para FALSO asumiendo que siempre habrá un mes con un valor mayor que `0`.

## Referencia

- [Crear una fórmula de matriz](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Crear-una-f%C3%B3rmula-de-matriz-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)